# what this assignment operation is called in c/c++?

Tags: c, variable-assignment

I know basics of c/c++
recently, I have been through a rather strange looking assignment

```
int a=1,b=2,c=5;  
int x = (a,b,c);
```

oddly enough, value of x is 5.
honestly, i would have searched Google if only i knew what this assignment operation is called.
any help ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`,` in second statement is called comma operator. It evaluates from left to right and the value of the last operand (sub-expression) will become the value of the entire expression. In case

```
int x = (a,b,c);
```

`a` is evaluated first, its value is discarded then `b` is evaluated and its value discarded then finally `c` is evaluated and its value get assigned to `x`.

Answer (score 3):

The assignment isn't called anything in particular, that's not it. This is a use of the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

It simply evaluates all the arguments, in left-to-right order, and the result is the value of the last (rightmost) expression.

Tne parenthesis are crucial here, without them it becomes plain initialzation, this:

```
int x = a, b,c;
```

does something completely diferent: it declares and initializes `x` to the value of `a`, and then generates re-declaration errors on `b` and `c`; the above line does not compile.

Note that this is distinct from the comma in the opening clause of a `for` loop.

Comment: "Note that this is distinct from the comma in the opening clause of a `for` loop." In what way?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yeah, that sucked. I blame Friday afternoon. I rewrote it now, thanks. Thanks sharth, too!